# Python XLSXWRITER - CONCATENTATE Error when loading Spreadsheet

Tags: python, concatenation, xlsxwriter

I am trying to concatenate variables and text  into a formula.

I am using:

worksheet.write_formula(wb_line_no, 1, '=CONCATENATE("Once:", f_ONCE, "CAR:", f_CAR, ":;"')

[image: Formula Error]

Can anyone point me to how to resolve and fix this line?

Comment: I noticed that CONCATENATE is actually CONCAT in xlsxwriter so I tried this:

worksheet.write_formula(wb_line_no, 1, '=_xlfn_CONCAT("Once:", f_ONCE, "CAR:", f_CAR, ":;"')

With no success :-(

Comment: I noticed a syntax error and tried this:

 worksheet.write_formula(wb_line_no, 1, '=_xlfn.CONCAT("Once:", f_ONCE, "CAR:", f_CAR, ":;")')

with no success :-(